# Searching dictionary for values

Tags: python, dictionary, count

Looking to count the number of males in a dictionary over the age of 20.

I have the following dictionary

```
i={'joe':("male",25), 'fred':("male",39), 'susan':("female",20)}
```

i know how to search the dictionary for a key for example

```
print ('joe' in i)
```

returns true but

```
print ('male' in i.values())
print ('male in i)
```

both return false. how can i get it to return true
Ultimately i am trying to count the number of males over a certain age in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    i={'joe':("male",25), 'fred':("male",39), 'susan':("female",20)}

    'joe' in i 
    equals
    'joe' in i.keys()

where i.keys() == ['joe', 'fred', 'susan']
```

Now,

```
i.values()
[('female', 20), ('male', 25), ('male', 39)]
```

here, each element for example ('female', 20) is a tuple and you are trying to compare it with a string which will give you false.

```
So when you do 
print ('male' in i.values()) -> returns false

print ('male in i) -> 'male' not in i.keys()
```

Solution would be as follows:

```
sum(x=='male' and y > 20 for x, y in i.values())

or

count = 0
for x, y in i.values():
    if x == 'male' and y > 20:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within `sum`:

```
In [1]: dictionary = {'joe':("male",25), 'fred':("male",39), 'susan':("female",20)}
In [2]: sum(gender=='male' for gender, age in dictionary.values() if age > 20)
Out[2]: 2
```

The condition `gender=='male'` will result in `True` or `False` which will be evaluated as 1 or 0. This will make it possible to count the valid conditions by summing up the final result.

Comment: thanks - how would i then check if males are between certain ages

Comment: @chrischris Just add the condition at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through key and value in dict using `.iter()` function. Then you can check for the values at 0 index for "male" and 1 index for age.

```
count = 0
for key, value in i.iter():
    if value[0] == "male" and value[1] > 20:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = [x for x, y in token.items() if "joe" in y]
```

Gives a list of all keys that have "joe" in their values.